# How do I set up a simple login system in pyramid?

Tags: python, session, session-cookies, pyramid

I've read the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be a *conclusive* tutorial that has the entire process where someone logs in, and their session is maintained via beaker or the default session system then logs out(or I haven't found it). From my understanding so far:

```
if 'form.submit' in request.POST:
    usr = request.params['username']
    pw = request.params['password']

/*** verify username/password logic ***/

    headers = remember(request, usr_id)
    return HTTPFound(location = welcome_screen, headers = headers)
```

headers() basically creates a cookie that identifies the session right? After that, I can access said session via beaker like so?:

```
request.session['usr_id']
```

... and to log out and invalidate the session I use:

```
headers = forget(request, usr)
return HTTPFound(location = logout_screen, headers = headers)
```

I'm just trying to create a very simple app that allows someone to log in and logout; im not using a db backend; the username and passwords are held in a global variable and will not change(this is just something im playing with to learn sessions and authentication).

Comment: You need a datastore because your global variable will be released back into the memory everytime response is sent.  You can simply use a text file if you want but you can't use memory on a web app in the same way you use it in a regular app.

Comment: You mix up Authentication & Authorization with sessioning stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is simple app that allows login and logout:

```
@view_config(route_name='main', renderer='main.mako')                          
def main_view(request):                                                        
    return {}                                                                  


@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='login.mako')                        
def login_view(request):                                                       
    login = request.params.get('login')                                        
    password = request.params.get('password')                                  
    if request.method == 'POST':                                               
        if login and USERS.get(login) == password:                             
            headers = remember(request, login)                                 
            return HTTPFound('/', headers=headers)                             
    return {}                                                                  


@view_config(route_name='logout')                                              
def logout(request):                                                           
    headers = forget(request)                                                  
    return HTTPFound(location='/', headers=headers)                            


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                     
    # configuration settings                                                   
    settings = {}                                                              
    settings['mako.directories'] = os.path.join(here, 'templates')             
    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy('sosecret', hashalg='sha512')   
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()                                    
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)                                   
    config.include('pyramid_mako')                                             
    config.add_static_view('static', os.path.join(here, 'static'))             
    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)                             
    config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)                              
    config.add_route('main', '/')                                              
    config.add_route('login', '/login')                                        
    config.add_route('logout', '/logout')                                      
    config.scan()                                                              
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()                                               
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)                                 
    server.serve_forever()
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/bacher09/b638c9537eace0cb8177).

> headers() basically creates a cookie that identifies the session right?
>   After that, I can access said session via beaker like so?

Yes you are almost right. It creates cookie that identifies user, session use other cookie.
You can access to user_id via `request.authenticated_userid`.
`AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` is backend that uses signed cookie, when you call `remember(request, user)` it returns headers with cookie signed by your secret key. When you call `forget(request)` is just return headers that would remove this cookie.
**Note**: if user would know your secret key, than he can authenticate as any user.

Also you may create your own
auth backend that would be using other methods (maybe [http basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)). With pyramid also bundled some [other auth backends](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/authentication.html). If you want change cookie life time you can set `max_age` param of `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` backend. For more info see [class docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/authentication.html#pyramid.authentication.AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy).

Comment: thanks this is very clear, but I don't get how the session is created and canceled in relation to the user being authenticated? how do i start and then later invalidate the users session cookie? Just create it when the user is authenticated, and clear it when they log out? And what about the max_life for the session cookie?

Comment: To change cookie life time you may set `max_age` param of [AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/authentication.html#pyramid.authentication.AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy)

Comment: Pay attention to calls using `remember` and `forget`. This is what triggers authentication state.

Comment: @SaschaGottfried Your [attempted edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5951673) proposes to change far too much of Slava's answer here. Please add specific comments as to how it should be changed, or update *your* answer with the information you want to include. Editing an answer should not alter its intent.

Answer (score 1):

For reference purposes: A simple google search for `pyramid remember forget` will show a lot of website explaining the topic and share sample code. A concise example is listed within Pyramid Quick Tutorial.

- [Pyramid Quick Tutorial - Logins with Authentication](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/quick_tutorial/authentication.html)

Lots of official pyramid tutorials a featuring auth-related topics as well

- [Pyramid Tutorials](http://pyramid-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)